# Problems 4.1 and 4.2 (Sean Carroll, General Relativity)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravity

Well, I can not solve these two questions. Could someone help me solve them? (Exercise 4.1) The Lagrange density for electromagnetism in curved space is $$\mathcal{L}=\sqrt{-g}\left(-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu}+A_\mu J^\mu\right),$$ where $J^\mu$ is the conserved current. (a) Derive the energy-momentum tensor by functional differentiation with respect to the metric; (b) Consider adding a new term to the Lagrangian, $\mathcal{L}'=\beta R^{\mu \nu}g^{\rho \sigma}F_{\mu \rho}F_{\nu \sigma}$. How are Maxwell's equations altered in the presence of this term? Einstein's equation? Is the current still conserved? (Exercise 4.2) We showed how to derive Einstein's equation by varying the Hilbert action with respect
to the metric. They can also be derived by treating the metric and connection as independent degrees of freedom and varying separately with respect to them; this is known as the Palatini formalism. That is, we consider the action $$S=\int d^4x\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu \nu}R_{\mu \nu}(\Gamma),$$ where the Ricci tensor is thought of as constructed purely from the connection, not using the metric. Variation with respect to the metric gives the usual Einstein's equations, but for a Ricci tensor constructed from a connection that has no a priori relationship to the metric. Imagining from the start that the connection is synunetric (torsion free), show that variation of this action with respect to the connection coefficients leads to the requirement that the connection be metric compatible, that is, the Christoffel connection. Remember that Stokes's theorem, relating the integral of the covariant divergence of a vector to an integral of the vector over the boundary, does not work for a general covariant derivative. The best strategy is to write the connection coefficients as a sum
of the Christoffel symbols $\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\mu \nu}$ and a tensor $C^\lambda_{\hspace{0.2cm}\mu \nu}$, $\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu \nu}=\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\mu \nu}+C^\lambda_{\hspace{0.2cm}\mu \nu},$ and then show that $C^\lambda_{\hspace{0.2cm}\mu \nu}$ must vanish.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Comment: This site isn't a homework help site. Instead, we deal with questions about physics concepts. To prevent closure of your question, please consider asking about the specific physics concept that prevents you from solving the problem.

Comment: With this approach (no effort shown), he'd be rejected also on the best HW Help site out there, www.physicsforums.com.